# AWS CloudWatch alarm for Lambda Invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to monitor a Lambda function based on the “invocation” metric. Specifically, I want the alarm to trigger if it hasn’t been invoked at least once. I've set up the following alarm and it hasn't triggered in 24 hours. I've made sure that Lambda has also not triggered however this alarm never goes into "ALARM" state. Any advice would be helpful.

```
Threshold: Invocations < 1 for 1 datapoints within 5 minutes
Statistic: Sum
Period: 5 minutes
Metric Name: Invocations
Namespace: AWS/Lambda
Datapoints to alarm: 1 out of 1
```

Comment: How have you configured it to treat missing data? The Invocations metric is only written if there are invocations (i.e. it won't write a value of `0`)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm treating missing data as "notBreaching". I guess this is why the alarm is not triggering?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be why.

Comment: @PMah problem with this is that it will always be in ALARM state. ALARM will go to OK state when Lambda is invoked once but after the evaluation period lapses, it will go back to ALARM state. Have to figure out a different way to do this.

Comment: @user2051904 please provide solution if you have got any fix for this?

Comment: @codeSeeker “ you can set your evaluation period to a day, and it will alarm when the Lambda function has not been invoked for a day or more. That's not exactly the same, but I think it's as close as you can get”. A user suggested this and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Invocations metric is only written if there are invocations (i.e. it won't write a value of `0`).

Therefore, for use cases such as this, where you *want* the alarm to trigger when the metric has not been written, you need to configure it to treat missing data as `breaching`.

Documentation for this is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html#alarms-and-missing-data).

Comment: problem with this is that it will always be in ALARM state. ALARM will go to OK state when Lambda is invoked once but after the evaluation period lapses, it will go back to ALARM state.

Comment: Is that not what you want? I assumed from your question that you wanted to alarm if it has not been invoked within the past 5 minutes. I don't think its possible to check whether it has ever been invoked, as the longest allowed evaluation period is a day.

Comment: I have a Lambda function that is invoked every day. I want an alarm that tells me when Lambda function was NOT invoked that day.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can set your evaluation period to a day, and it will alarm when the Lambda function has not been invoked for a day or more. That's not _exactly_ the same, but I think it's as close as you can get.